# finding smallest unique element in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python that contains strings:

```
["foo/bar","foo/bar/baz","foo/bar/qux"]
```

I'm trying to separate out the smallest elements in that list that are not contained in any other longer elements. In this case, I want to return a list `["foo/bar/baz","foo/bar/qux"]` as they are not contained in any longer elements. I don't want `"foo/bar"`, as it is contained in `"foo/bar/baz"` and `"foo/bar/qux"`. I've been trying nested for and if statements here but I can't seem to get it right. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide what you got so far. It can have a far greater learning effect if we can just correct your mistakes.

Comment: Is `b/c` contained in `a/b/c`, despite not starting with `a/`?  Is `foo/ba` contained in `foo/bar/baz`, i.e., are slashes "special" in some way here?

Comment: This seems like you are trying to find all leaf directories.  Is that the case?

Comment: How large is your typical list?

Comment: @JustinDanielson the typical list is hundreds of items

Comment: So is a brute force solution going to be good enough? This for loop is going to check over N^2 items. So for a list of 100 items. You have 99 checks for the first item, 98 for the second, 97 for the 3rd, and so on. n(n+1) / 2 checks... that can get expensive. As long as the list doesn't get to thousands, it should be okay.

You could experience UI lag while all this processing is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're really looking for leaf directories (i.e., "contained in" really means "prefixed by" and slashes *are* special), here's a simple algorithm:

```
def leaf_dirs(dirlist):
    """Given a list of directories, find leaf directories"""
    parents = {}
    for path in dirlist:
        parts = path.split('/')
        if parts[0] == '':
            raise ValueError("can't handle rooted directory %s" % path)
        parent = '/'.join(parts[:-1])
        parents[parent] = True
    return [path for path in dirlist if path not in parents]
```

Basically, all "parent directory" names are put into a dictionary, and then we filter away those names.  In the case of "foo/bar/baz" and "foo/bar/quux", the parent path (foo/bar) is entered twice, but we don't really care.

Edit: to fix the point noted by Omri Barel, instead of just using `parts[:-1]`:

```
        while parts:
            parts.pop() # strip last path component
            parent = '/'.join(parts)
            parents[parent] = True
```

This strips the last component and enters the parent.  (I've deliberately entered the empty string here, it's a little simpler that way.)

Comment: What about `foo` in the example? (in other words, what about the list `['foo', 'foo/bar/baz', 'foo/bar/qux']`?)

Comment: @OmriBarel: good point, should loop for all parent paths, removing elements as we go.

Comment: @torek What do you mean by "deliberately entered the empty string"? I followed your logic until then.

Comment: Easy example, the path 'foo' by itself: `parts = 'foo'.split('/')` is the same as `parts = ['foo']`.  The `while parts:` loop is entered, we pop off the one element, then we make `parent = '/'.join([])` which sets parent to `''`': the empty string.  So `parents['']` is always `True`, and `leaf_dirs()` will filter out empty strings.

Comment: BTW, since we're only using the keys of the dictionary, it would be reasonable to make `parents` a set of strings instead: `parents = set([])` and then `parents |= set([parent])`.  Also, if paths tend to be very long and duplicative, you could break out of the inner loop as soon as some path is in `parents`, since that parent's parents will by definition also be included.  But those just make it less obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I would sort the list first (in this case, it is already sorted though), and then just compare each string to the next string:

Using List Comprehension:

```
l = ["foo/bar/baz/abc", "fo/bar","foo/bar/baz","foo/bar/qux", "foo/bar/qux/abc"]
l.sort()

length = len(l)

new_list = [v for (i, v) in enumerate(l) if (index < length - 1) and (l[i] not in l[i + 1])]

new_list.append(l[-1])  // Append last element (as it will always be there).

print new_list
```

*Output*:

```
['fo/bar', 'foo/bar/baz/abc', 'foo/bar/qux/abc']
```

Comment: Why break? The list could contain more than one element that needs to be removed.

Comment: @OmriBarel. I thought OP just wanted to remove the smallest one.

Comment: My understanding is that he is looking for all the strings in the list that are not contained in other strings in the list.

Comment: Does performance matter? This won't scale well. This code only solves the example problem.

Comment: @OmriBarel. Hmm. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = []

for i in old_list:
    found = False
    for j in old_list:
       if i in j and i != j:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Very poor perfomance...

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["foo/bar","foo/bar/baz","foo/bar/qux", "foo/bar/qax/dda"]
sorted_l = sorted(l, key=len)
length, found = -1, False
for i,v in enumerate(sorted_l):
    if found and not length == len(v): break
    for vv in sorted_l[i+1:]:
        if v in vv: break
    else: 
        print v
        length = len(v)
        found = True
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you should actually build a tree model, then take the paths from the leaves to the root.

This is a python tree library that will likely be useful: https://github.com/caesar0301/pyTree

Comment: This exactly.  It seems like there is a much easier way to solve this.